# lambda function responde object is not handled

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am invoking following function in the lambda function which is calling another function with callback. inside the callback the response object seems to be not treated properly as it gives response invalid error in the alexa simulator. Function looks like

```
function handleFirstEventRequest(intent, session, response) {
    var repromptText = "With History Buff, you can get historical events for any day of the year. For example, you could say today, or August thirtieth. Now, which day do you want?";

    var sessionAttributes = {};
    var cardContent = "";

    var cardTitle = "Events on ";
    //response.tell("There is an issue here vik");
    getJsonEventsFromWikipedia(function (events) {
        var speechText = "";
        sessionAttributes.text = events;
        session.attributes = sessionAttributes;
        if (events.length == 0) {
            speechText = "There is a problem connecting to Wikipedia at this time. Please try again later.";
            cardContent = speechText;
            response.tell(speechText);
        } else{
              console.log("vik::::::::::::: wikipedia response received");
              console.log("values are:" + events);
             var speechOutput = {
            speech: "hi how are you",
            type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
        };
        var repromptOutput = {
            speech: "hi how are you",
            type: AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.PLAIN_TEXT
        };
            console.log("before response");
            response.ask(speechOutput,  repromptOutput);
            console.log("after response");
        }
    });
}
```

however, outside the getJsonEventsFromWikipedia  response works perfectly fine. I am nor sure what is going wrong here. lambda function logs shows no error etc

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that your response is invalid. When you invoke it in the simulator, what JSON do you see coming back? You didn't indicate above. When you invoke it, what comes up in the Lambda logs? You didn't indicate that either. Did you try testing your lambda function with a SessionStart event? I think that if you try these you should be able to find the error in your code or setup.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell without full context. But assuming that you are using alexa skill in a not very unusual way, most probable cause is:

getJsonEventsFromWikipedia is async. Your function exits successfully before executing your callback and the Lambda Callback function is invoked by some other path in the code or not invoked at all before the Lambda entry function returns. The solution is to wait for your call to getJsonEventsFromWikipedia to respond, and exit your function only after you've made sure that you handled it.